# How do you populate a List of Lists in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Recently I wrote some code akin to the following

```
namespace Foo
{
    public struct Bar
    {
        public float val;

        public Bar(float val) {  this.val = val; }  
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rows = 3;
            int cols = 4;

            List<List<Bar>> mat = Enumerable.Repeat(
                   Enumerable.Repeat(default(Bar), cols).ToList(),
                   rows
               ).ToList();
            
            foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, rows * cols))
            {
                int row = i / cols;
                int col = i % cols;
                mat[row][col] = new Bar((float)i);
            }

            foreach (var row in Enumerable.Range(0, rows))
            {
                foreach (var col in Enumerable.Range(0, cols))
                {
                    Console.Write(mat[row][col].val + " ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which yields the surprising (to me) output of

```
8 9 10 11
8 9 10 11
8 9 10 11
```

I believe the problem is that in the LINQ expression. The inner LINQ expression is correct because since `Bar` is a `struct` it will use value semantics when repeating the `struct`, but the outer LINQ expression will then repeat references to the same `List<T>` because a `List<T>` is a class and thus uses reference semantics.

My questions are (1) is the above explanation of this problem correct? and (2) what is a better way to initialize a `List<List<T>>` without using explicit nested loops and that results in distinct rows?

Comment: That's correct but it seems to me that you're excluding the idiomatic solution: explicit nested loops. You're just making the problem artificially harder to solve. (I don't consider `foreach` over a `Range` to be idiomatic either, more like a hack to avoid `for` loops)

Comment: Even better would be to make a class that represents what you are working with, e.g. a Matrix class in this example. Another example is 'DataTable', with explicit Row and Column classes

Comment: Personally I don't see a problem with using `Enumerable` and `foreach` instead of an explicit `for` loop if performance is not a problem. I do think it's odd to have a list of lists as part of your data structure though. What do the inner lists represent? Make a type for that, and give them a nice constructor or static factory methods you can call. Those may wrap a Linq call or may be implemented by hand, and the caller doesn't have to know.

Comment: You can boil your code down to this: `List<List<Bar>> mat = Enumerable.Range(0, rows * cols).GroupBy(i => i / cols).Select(x => x.Select(y => new Bar(y)).ToList()).ToList();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the inner lists of the outer list contain identical `val` values is that the first argument to [`Enumerable.Repeat<List<Bar>>(List<Bar>, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.repeat) is evaluated **only once**, so they are in fact **the same list** repeated `rows` times.

To convince yourself of that, you could assert that all of the items of `mat` are equal using `object.ReferenceEquals()`:

```
Assert.That(mat.All(row => object.ReferenceEquals(row, mat[0]))); // Does not throw.
```

Thus your `foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, rows * cols))` loop overwrites the contents of that single list multiple times, with the contents of the final iterations winning.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EPLcm9).

Assuming you want distinct lists with the following contents:

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11
```

You could use nested calls to [`Enumerable.Range(int start, int count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range) concisely to create your jagged list of distinct lists as follows:

```
var mat = Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
    .Select(iRow => Enumerable.Range(iRow*cols, cols).Select(iCell => new Bar(iCell)).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ao9bgi).